# distinguish between first page load and router <Link />?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

i have a route which renders an overlay modal.
i want it to animate-in if i navigate from the UI, 
and be loaded as static when navigating from the address bar or after a refresh.

i use nodejs and react + react-router.

i thought about using my universal redux setup to match a state prop for this issue, but maybe there's a much more elegant solution

thanks!

Comment: You can see something like this in the [React Router Pinterest example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/cbc8f87e2094a4c10aeeaec438b74cc4238df2aa/examples/pinterest/app.js#L37) that may help

Comment: thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by testing the `prevPath` property on the `props.location` object

```
const [isFirstLoad,setIsFirstLoad] = useState(false)
const {location} = props

useEffect(()=> {
    props.prevPath ? setIsFirstLoad(true) : setIsFirstLoad(false)
}, [location])

return <Modal animate={!isFirstLoad}/>
```

Each render `UseEffect` will test the `props.location` (similar to `componentWillReceiveProps()`) to check if the previous path is different. On load the `prevPath` property won't exist, so it will be `false`.